# JSF request scope with get parameter

Tags: jsf, parameters, parameter-passing, managed-bean

i know there are many similar threads but no like mine:

I have a requestscope bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable{
    private String username = ""; //managed by textbox
    private String password = ""; //managed by textbox

    private String id ="-";

    //Load the Parameter as usual:
    @PostConstruct
    public void fetchParams(){
        System.out.println("FETCH PARAMS");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String id = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
        if(id == null || id.length() == 0) return;
        setId(id);
    }

    // getters & setters

    public void doSomething(){ //executed when clicked on the sumbit-button on the jsf-site
        StaticFunctions.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

The code does following:
it retrieves the get-parameter "id" and saves it into String id (confirmed by string.out....).

**But when the method doSomething() is executed and the previously stored "id" is read and returns "-" (like nothing happened).**

why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ManagedBean is `@RequestScoped` and will be destroyed at the end of the request. When `doSomething()` is executed the user submitted the form and started a new request. 
So you should see "FETCH PARAMS" twice in the console because two Beans are created but for the second request `id` is  `null`.

You can find a detailed explanation about the four JSF-Scopes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031941).

Comment: but is there any solution for my problem? how can i execute doSomething() correctly? username and password are executed correctly... only the id makes problems (because it doesn't have a textfield or anything?

Comment: Choose a wider scope or [pass the param to the bean](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean)